# Get users count whose latitude and logitude within 15 miles from logged in user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, geolocation

Let me explain my case :

First of all user will login.
Now in database I am saving Latitude and Longitude for that logged in user.

Now I want to get count of all other users whose latitude and longitude are within 15 miles from that  logged in user.

I have tried with some default function of .net but it did not work.

Comment: We do distance calculations in SQL Server with its built-in support for geography data types. So if you are using that, then that is an option. If you need a clientside option, you probably need a library like this: https://github.com/sibartlett/Geo. Haven't tried this one myself though.

Comment: share your c# code that you have tried, and explain what did not work. Give a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you store your locations as a `geography::Point` in sqlserver? If not, you should consider it as it makes this easy, like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE location.STDistance(@loggedInUserLocation) < 15 * 1609.34`

Comment: That said I don't think there's a good way to index a query like this using the geography so you might want to do a preliminary cull of non qualifying users by excluding those whose lat long is outside a "square" of plus minus half a degree around your user location; that should exclude users more than approximately 35 miles away and you can then STDistance the rest

Comment: SQL server supports [spatial indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15), so the WHERE clause that starts with a geography method like `STDistance` will make use of it, if a spatial index was created on that column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many users you have, as my solution might be inefficient for a large userbase. If i understood your question correct, all you want to do is calulate the hypotenuse.

```
int[,] user = new int[10, 2]
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   Random rand = new Random();
   int cero = rnd.Next(1, 30);
   int one = rnd.Next(1, 30);
   user[i, 0] = cero;
   user[i, 1] = one;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   if ((user[i, 0] ^ 2) + (user[i, 1] ^ 2) <= 225) // <- 15^2 == 225
   {
       Console.WriteLine("User " + i.ToString() + " is in Range.");
       count++;
   }
}

Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

This is a small sample code that should solve the Problem